# How can I call a schedule class from trigger before the due_date__c field?

Tags: apex, trigger, controller

I want to call the schedulable class before 15 days of due_date__c field.I have written batch class and schedulable class.Now, don't know what to do?

Comment: see this link https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008zgyIAA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by

```
//
// IN YOUR TRIGGER --- launch a Scheduled Apex class called "ScheduledClass"
//

// Build a CRON Expression corresponding to 1 second from now

    Datetime executeTime = (System.now()).addSeconds(1);
    String cronExpression = util_Utilities.GetCRONExpression(executeTime);

//System.debug('***Cron Expression: ' + cronExpression);

// Instantiate a new Scheduled Apex class
ScheduledClass scheduledJob = new ScheduledClass();

// Schedule our class to run at our given execute time, 
// naming executeTime so that the the Schedule name will be Unique  
System.schedule('ScheduledJob ' + executeTime.getTime(),cronExpression,scheduledJob);
```

//
// UTILITY CLASS 
//

```
// Builds a CRON Expression out of a Datetime
public static String GetCRONExpression(Datetime dt) {
   return ('' + dt.second() + ' ' + dt.minute() + ' ' + dt.hour() + ' ' + dt.day() + ' ' + dt.month() + ' ? ' + dt.year());
}
```

But I would suggest to be very careful, about launching your scheduled Job from a trigger, as you NEED to check to make sure that you have available Scheduled Jobs. You can only have 10 Scheduled Jobs at a given time. Use something like this to check to make sure you have enough Jobs:

public static final Integer MAX_SCHEDULED_JOBS  = 10;

```
// Determine whether the maximum number
// of Scheduled Jobs has been reached
public static Boolean MaxScheduledJobsReached() {
   return (GetScheduledJobs().size() >= MAX_SCHEDULED_JOBS) ;
}

// Returns all Scheduled Apex jobs that have not been started yet 
public static List<CronTrigger> GetScheduledJobs() {
   return [select Id, NextFireTime 
           from CronTrigger 
            where State in ('WAITING','ACQUIRED','EXECUTING')
           or NextFireTime != NULL];
}
```

As far as launching Batch Apex jobs, I usually have a utility method in my Batch classes that makes it easy to launch a new Batch Job.